# Spring MVC 3.1.1 External Resources not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with mapping external resources. Specifically, in my app-servlet.xml, I have the following:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
   <property name="cookieName" value="lang"/>
   <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>
<mvc:interceptors>
   <mvc:interceptor>
      <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
      <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
         <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
      </bean>
   </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="file:C:/Users/username/Desktop/translations/translation"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
   <property name="messageConverters">
      <array>
         <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/plain;charset=UTF-8"/>
         </bean>
      </array>
   </property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/content/**" location="file:C:/Users/username/Desktop/content/"/>
<!--    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>-->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

My web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have tried any possible combination and also with and without `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` but when I try to reach a page with an external resource, I see in the Network tab of my browser that the application returns 200 but the content is not loaded.

I added a breakpoint in the ResourceHttpRequestHandler class and I show that the method `setLocations(List<Resource> locations)` invoked at startup but the `handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException` is not invoked when I try to load the content from e.g. `http://localhost:8080/app/content/testImage.png`,

The logs are not suggesting anything also.

I also tried to map the external location through the Tomcat server.xml but with no results.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: For starters remove the `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` declaration. That interferes with the `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: I have also tried that didn't work.

Comment: Nonetheless it interferes with `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and shouldn't be there. Also make sure you don't have a controller that catches everything that doesn't match or something mapped to `/content` instead of the content handler.

Comment: I see. Also, none of the controllers are interfered with the `/content` mapping also.

Comment: Make sure of that. Also enable debug or trace logging to actually see what is handling your request.

Comment: The error I'm getting is [PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/content/image.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'app'`

Comment: Please, after removing said `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` and cranking up the logging do the request and add the logging.